# XAML Designer shows error on custom behaviors in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015, blend

I am doing my first steps in Visual Studio 2015 and Blend for Visual Studio 2015. The XAML designer fails to show a preview of the UI and keeps marking all the behaviors with errors. To demonstrate the problem I have created a minimal solution that presents the problem. I have a solution that contains only a single WPF application called **Test.Ui**, (target .net framework is 4.5). The WPF application references the Blend Dlls: **Microsoft.Expression.Interactions** and **System.Windows.Interactivity**, both in version 4.5.

The behavior class implementation is minimal:

```
namespace Test.Ui
{
    public class MyBehavior : Behavior<Grid>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML that uses it is as follows:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.Ui"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 
    x:Class="Test.Ui.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:MyBehavior/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The designer both in Blend and in Visual Studio keep showing an error mark under the line  with an error that says: 
"The type 'MyBehavior' from assembly 'Test.Ui' is built with an older version of the Blend SDK, and is not supported in Windows Presentation Framework 4 project.

Note that it is not a WPF 4 project, but rather a WPF 4.5, and that the application runs fine. It only has errors in the designer.

I am using the latest version of Blend Dlls.
[image]

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem, but only when I reference the 4.0.0.0 version of System.Windows.Interactivity. When  I reference the 4.5.0.0 version of S.W.Interactivity, all seems well. In short, the issue you have outlined is not reproducible under the conditions you've specified.

Comment: I am facing the same issue . Is it resolved ?